# PHP - why can't I get rid of this session id cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to troubleshoot a logout function for a web app. When you're logged in, the app has several cookies set for its domain. Here's the current logout procedure:

- You click a link, which sends you to a logout page
- The logout page runs a function that calls `session_destroy()` and also loops through all the cookies for the domain and sets them to expire in the past (see code below)
- The logout page then redirects to a login page, which is straight HTML.

At the end of this process, all the other cookies are unset, but the `PHPSESSID` cookie is still there, has the same value, and is still set to expire at the end of the session.

**What am I missing here?**

Here's the logout function I mentioned above:

```
function log_out_current_user() {

        // Destroy the session
        if (isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_destroy();
        }

        // Expire all of the user's cookies for this domain:
        // give them a blank value and set them to expire
        // in the past
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
            $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
            foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
                $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
                $name = trim($parts[0]);
                setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
                setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
            }
            // Explicitly unset this cookie - shouldn't be redundant,
            // but it doesn't hurt to try
            setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time()-1000);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are not removing it with the same parameters as it was created. Use [`session_get_cookie_params`](http://php.net/session_get_cookie_params) to obtain those. To be portable you should get the name of the cookie via [`session_name`](http://php.net/session_name). Here's a small script to do that:

```
$params = session_get_cookie_params();
setcookie(session_name(), '', 0, $params['path'], $params['domain'], $params['secure'], isset($params['httponly']));
```

Comment: This is the most helpful thing i've found in this subject. It turns out i was missing one character in path. This takes care of all the work and prevents you from making a mistake. Thank you!