# session_destroy() doesn't work with PHP >7.0 on server

Tags: php, session, destroy

I'm new to stackoverflow but I'm not new to PHP.
Now I've a funny problem:

I'm developing with XAMPP 7.1.11 with PHP 7.1.11 locally, doing logging out from sessions with

```
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

in a logout.php file. On top of the page there's a

```
session_start();
```

and in past everything went without any problem.
Now I did a php version change  at the provider from PHP 7.0 to 7.1 and it's not possible to log out any more, the session informations seem not be deleted.
I searched the internet but I didn't find a helpful hint and the provider told me to ask some PHP forums.

I tried all hints in the topics

[why session_destroy() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working)

[The session_destroy(); doesn't work correctly on server with php 5.3.21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365944/the-session-destroy-doesnt-work-correctly-on-server-with-php-5-3-21)

and many more but nothing is working. A Change from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.2 at the provider doesn't help as well.

What I'm doing wrong? as I said: locally everything works normally.

Thanks for your help!

Here's the complete logout.php file:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!-- Import Wordpress -->
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-load.php'); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<link href="cpplattform.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'rightbar' ) ) : ?>col-md-8<?php else : ?>col-md-12<?php endif; ?>">
            <div class="content">                   
                <h2 class="entry-title">Logout</h2>
                <!----------------------------------------------------->                
                <section class = "conf">    
                    <i class='fa fa-power-off fa-5x' style ='color:#00ADED'></i>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    Your logout was successful! Good Bye!
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <a class="btn btn-md btn-inverse" href="cplogin.php">Login again</a></p>
                    <?php

                        $_SESSION = array();
                        $_SESSION['username'] = "";                     
                        session_destroy();                      
                    ?>                  
                </section>              
                <!----------------------------------------------------->
            </div><!--content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Change all links from Wordpress -->
<script src="cplinkmodify.js"></script>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I added some static pages and imported a Wordpress theme.

Comment: **Note: You do not have to call session_destroy() from usual code. Cleanup $_SESSION array rather than destroying session data.** - From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Comment: Show us your code page where you set `$_SESSION = array();` This should be all you need to do. Check you have set `session_start();` on *this* page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why session\_destroy() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working)

Comment: @Chirag: Thank you. As I mentioned in my question: I already tried those hints in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472123/why-session-destroy-not-working and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: You do not have to call session_destroy() from usual code. Cleanup $_SESSION array rather than destroying session data.

- From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Show us your code page where you set `$_SESSION = array();` This should be all you need to do. Check you have set `session_start();` on *this* page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = []; //empty the array. 

--End of file.
```

If you want to make *absolutely sure* that it works ok you can try using something like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = []; //empty array. 
session_write_close();
```

But note any further edits to any session data on this script will *not* be saved once the script completes.

---

You may also have an issue if your scripts are in different folders and the *local* **php.ini** session name is different in these different folders... Different names, different sessions.

Central PHP.ini:

> ```
> session.name=somethingSessiony
> ```

local folder specific PHP.ini

> ```
> session.name=somethingsessiony
> ```

If you feel this may be a factor try something like this:

```
error_log(__FILE__." : " .print_r(session_name(),true));
```

In both the file that clears the session data and the file that should be reading the "empty" session data.

Comment: Hi Martin! Thanks for your answer in advance! I added the complete file and will check your hints with local php.ini files.

Comment: I did'nt change anything - and now it works with PHP 7.1 at the provider. Can't say, what it was. I now  added `session_write_close();` - hopefully it helps to avoid problems in future.