# PHPSESSID won't die

Tags: php, session, session-cookies, sessionid

I'm trying to make a simple logout script for my site, but for some reason, I can't kill this cookie.  I was able to kill another cookie which I named "fontCookie" but this default-named one won't go away.  What could be causing this issue? This is what I have, and I repeat, fontCookie is being destroyed:

```
<?php  
session_start();  

if(isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])){

$_SESSION = array();


    if(isset($_COOKIE['fontCookie'])){

    setcookie('fontCookie', '', time() -42000);

    }
    if ( isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] ) ){

    setcookie( session_name(), '', time()-42000);

    }

    session_destroy();

    header('Location: http://google.com');
}
else{

    header('Location: http://google.com');
}


?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove the cookie...

Comment: @JohnVanDeWeghe, but why can't I remove it with code?  It only gets deleted if I use the GUI in my browser

Comment: When the cookies are marked as expired it's possible they aren't actually removed until the browser restarts. Did you check multiple browsers to see if that was the case?

Comment: Oh, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989347/php-why-cant-i-get-rid-of-this-session-id-cookie

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to call `session_name()` before `session_start()`

> The session name is reset to the default value stored in session.name
>   at request startup time. Thus, you need to call session_name() for
>   every request (**and before session_start() or session_register() are
>   called**). [refer here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting cookie like this.

```
 setcookie('fontCookie', '', time() -42000);
 $_COOKIE["fontCookie"] = null;
 unset($_COOKIE["fontCookie"] );
```