# Kohana 3.2 : Error reading session data (Debian Platform)

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.2

I have recently got my website launched on Debian platform.

However, I keep getting this '**Error reading session data**' whenever try to read the session data. I suspect it could be caused by corrupted session data.

I had tried to ini_set 'session.gc_probability' to 0, but still can't get thing right. As follows:

```
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 0);
```

And yes, it's using session 'native' driver.

Does anyone here encounter this problem before?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could be a bug - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028509/error-message-while-logging-in-in-kohana

Answer (score 1):

So this indeed is a bug but there is a way through :)
Every time you (or system class) call `Session::regenerate()` method (if you use Auth, then the `login` function uses it), call `Session::instance()->write();` right after, for example:

```
if (Auth::instance()->login($post['username'], $post['password']))
{
       Session::instance()->write();
       $this->request->redirect('somewhere');
}
```