# How to destroy session_id() in php?

Tags: php, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [(PHP) How to destroy the session cookie correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241769/php-how-to-destroy-the-session-cookie-correctly)

I'm doing a shopping cart in PHP. I am using `session_id()` to identify individual users. After saving the product order, I need to destroy the `session_id`. How will I do that?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're using the session id as a key in your database? If so, that's most probably a bad idea (tm)

Comment: Is there a typo in your heading ? Whats ``session_id()``

Answer (score 1):

use a `session_regenerate_id()`. It will change the session id, automatically invalidating the old one

For a good destroy, use the following on logout:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me try it. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `unset()` function is used to free the specified session variable:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
   unset($_SESSION['id']);
}
```

You can also completely destroy the session by calling the `session_destroy()` function:

```
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean, but this is how you destroy a session

```
 unset( $_SESSION['id'] )
```

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. 

I used the following statement to generate a unique id for the session. 

$sid = session_id();

I need to destroy the value in $sid after saving the orders in the database.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
session_regenerate_id();
```

instead. It will regenerate the Session ID.

See more information at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

Comment: You will still get the same session id that way if you restart the session.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Let me try it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using session ID is not the best way to go (although you could use [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php) to create new session ID) because you loose contents of cart if user logs out (for example he will start preparing order in work and would want to finish it home).

Much better, flexible and easier to control would be creating table:

```
CREATE TABLE carts (
    `id` INT,
    `user_id` INT
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try..

page1.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['userID'] = 123;
?>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); // start the session before using it
    session_destroy(); // delete the current session
    //$_SESSION['userID'] = 123;  // <---- NO LONGER EXISTS
    echo "Session destroyed!"; // inform the user of the changes
?>
```

Or you could just have the session_destroy(); in with your code