# How to logout from session and cookies

Tags: php, session, symfony, cookies, http-headers

I have symfony2 application. 
I want to clear all session and cookies and logout application using controller. but after logingout when i click on back button in browser it returns application page instead of Login page.
In PHP `header` is used to redirect page but in symfony i dont know how to out this problem.
here is my code.

**IndexAction**

```
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = new Loginsec();


    if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
        $session->clear();

        $username = $request->get('user');
        $password = $request->get('pass');
        $remember = $request->get('remember');
        if ($username != "" && $password != "") {
            $Login = $this->checklogin($username, $password);
            if ($Login) {

                if ($remember != '') {
                    $response = new Response();
                    $cookiename = new Cookie('cookname',$username,time()+3600*24*7,'/LoginProject');

                    $response->headers->setcookie($cookiename);
                    $response->setContent($cookiename);
                    $response->send();
                }


                //Manage Session

                $user->setUser($username);           
                $session->set('user',$username);
                $session->start();

                return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Company.html.twig', array('name' => $session->get('user'));
            } else {

                return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig', array('error' => 'Login Failed'));
            }
        } else {
            return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig', array('error' => 'Input required Fields'));
        }
    } else {

         //Get SESSION
        if ($session->has('user') && $session->has('pass')) {

            $login = $this->checklogin($session->get('user'), $session->get('pass'));

            if($login){
                      return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Company.html.twig', array('name' => $session->get('user'));


            }

        }elseif($request->cookies->get('cookname')){

                //Get Cookie
                $request=  $this->get('request');
                $login = $this->checklogin($request->cookies->get('cookname'),$request->cookies->get('cookpass')) ;
                if($login){
                    return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig', array('error' => 'Login Using Cookie'));
                }

            } else {
                return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig');
            }
    }
```

**logoutAction**

```
Public function logoutAction(Request $request) {

    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->clear('user');
    $session->remove('user');
    unset($session);

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->clearCookie('cookname') ;
    $response->send();

    return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:Login.html.twig');

}
```

Please help me if any Idea.

Comment: I had similar problems, but with the built login/logout Symfony2 system. I found then an answer to it and was the `invalidate session` parameter inside the config. Maybe could be useful for you too. Look for `invalidate()` at the `Session API` block: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [(PHP) How to destroy the session cookie correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241769/php-how-to-destroy-the-session-cookie-correctly)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because @Sameer is doing it with Symfony, and it has it's own methods. With Symfony you don't handle sessions directly, you do it through Symfony2 built methods.

Comment: Hey Dainis,  @DaniSancas is right in php,i can handle session operation but in symfony, Methods are diffrent then php methods.

Comment: Did my advice work? Hope it did!

Comment: Thankx bro but i can not understand what to do.will you reply me syntex.?

Comment: $session->invalidate()

Comment: @redbirdo thanks but it not work.It logout but back to profile page on clicking on back button of brower.

Comment: Yes, but if the user submits anything the session will be invalid and then it should redirect to login. I'm not sure what you mean by "in php header is used to redirect page". Do you mean set the header to prevent page caching, in which case back causes a page reload, which indirectly redirects to login? If so, that has nothing to do with the session, it's the page headers.

Comment: Have a look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html. You should be able to modify the profile page response (after render, before return) to disable caching.

Comment: I had this issue and added `invalidate_session: true` to the logout section of my firewall in `security.yml` (see: line 180 - http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html). I have recently changed to using the PDO session handler (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html) which has somehow stopped this from being an issue. Not sure if it's the PDO handler or just the multiple updates that I've done between setting `invalidate_session` and realising it wasn't needed anymore.

Comment: $redbirdo I exactly mean set the header to prevent page caching, in which case back causes a page reload, which indirectly redirects to login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just reviewing my questions and found this one. Actually it's solved long time ago.

Unset session variable using

```
$session->remove('<Parameter>');
```

Ex.

```
$session->remove('user');
```