# PHP PHPSESSID persists after calling session_name(***)

Tags: php, session, cookies

Can't seem to find the solution to the problem I'm having with my session.

```
$framework['session_name'] = "GenericSession";    

session_name($framework['session_name']);
session_set_cookie_params(0);
session_start();
```

In `$_SERVER`I find this:

```
 [HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=uc2h858qkktji15g3qojom2104;
                  GenericSession=4dde6ufeepq21kiro2r931vui7
```

Can anyone tell me why there is still a `PHPSESSID`? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: unset it and/or destroy it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried destroying it, but it still persists. If I print_r everything in $_SESSION I get all the data that's tied to the 'GenericSession'

Comment: is this cross-domain related? could be an issue here.

Comment: you've been given an answer. You now need to ask him.

Comment: It is not cross-domain related @Fred-ii-. I've accepted the answer that seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm glad to know that the question was solved, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPSESSID comes from your Browser Cookie.

You need to reset your Cookies for this website and you'll see only your new cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unset the cookie in the browser [See Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php). To do this, use `set_cookie`.

I have borrowed the following from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241769/php-how-to-destroy-the-session-cookie-correctly):

```
setcookie (session_id(), "", time() - 3600);
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
```