# Mozilla doesn't "Refresh" the page

Tags: caching, google-chrome, refresh, mozilla

I have a page with keith-wood's datepicker, and jqplot graphs. Basically, the date picker 1 is set to todays date by default, and date picker 2 is set to a day before. If you select a date in datepicker1, the date in datepicker2 goes a date before.

Now, all is well in chrome if I refresh, but in FF, if I refresh, the datepicker1 should come to default date, but it is not coming back to today, it goes on subtracting a day.

I did a ctrl+shift+r and it reloads as it should, but regular f5 will display the problem of caching.

How do I avoid this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cache+header+clear) `meta` in your page head, particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971721/how-to-use-http-cache-headers-with-php).

You can force a cache-clear, but keep in mind this will significantly affect your loading time.  Also, IE has a specific combination of headers that accomplish this task, so be careful to look for and test for those.

Comment: I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers, worked...

Comment: Thanks man :) This worked : <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

Comment: Yep, that looks familiar.  Glad to be of service.