# Check if page exists in cache, Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, caching, windows-8, frame

Is there a way to check if page/frame in Windows 8 application exists in cache? Let's assume I have two pages: Home and Clients (navigation cache enabled). When I navigate to clients from home (by button) clients are loaded from database in OnNavigatedTo method. I navigate back to Home by Back button and than again to Clients. Now I see that clients are loaded from cache, which is good, but than again from OnNavigatedTo method. I'd like to load clients from database only once, when I open page for the first time. Later just load clients from cache.

How can I check than if clients were previously loaded or load them only on first page load? Maybe some other method?

Thank you!

Comment: Assuming you are talking about webpages. From what I know from developing PHP based websites is that you specify whether the page may be cached, and if so, when it expires. So in general you are asking what page headers to set? Maybe this might be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971721/how-to-use-http-cache-headers-with-php

Comment: BTW, What has Windows 8 to do with anything? You tagged it with C#, so a .Net framework would be more appropriate, but that doesn't go into the title. Your question now suggests you are trying out a platform specific (Windows 8) feature/hack of accessing cached pages... (At Least to me...) EDIT: Oh I see now, I was thinking `ASP C#`. I have no understanding of Windows 8 Apps :)

Comment: Oh, sorry no I'm not talking about web pages. My question is about Windows 8 app.

Comment: I was gonna suggest kernel tag, what kind of question is this?

Comment: +1 I did Face this :) Ill share a work around

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution to it ...

Sinche no one wants to load from cache in metro app so it's always better to reset the  cache size for the respective frame. For pages where you want it to load from the cache. Just keep an if loop. and also check for the `forwardStack` in the `History` object.

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        ResetPageCache();
    }
}

private void ResetPageCache()
{
    var cacheSize = ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize;
    ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize = 0;
    ((Frame) Parent).CacheSize = cacheSize;
}
```

Here's a blog. Ill recommend you go through this first :)

[BLOG](http://www.jayway.com/2012/05/25/clearing-the-windows-8-page-cache/)

EDIT---------------------

Here are two links. Since i never faced the situation of loading the file from previous cache so I can share some findings :)

Here's the `accesscache` class

[Access cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.aspx)

and here's for winJS

[winJS cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701424.aspx)

the access cache might meet your requirement if you set caching to true for the pages you want :)

Comment: I would definitely like to load my page from cache. I'll correct my question.

Comment: in that case just have `NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;` . If the page is there in the cache it will automatically load it from there.

Comment: But this will happen in app. Ill share some thing more specific in an EDIt :)

Comment: Yeah, it does work but OnNavigatedTo method invokes every time I open this page. I want to load clients from database at first page opening and later get them from cache. That's why I want to know whether clients are in cache or was it the first time page is opened.

Comment: I guess you are on winJS ? or metro C#

Comment: I'm on C#, as tagged.

Comment: I did edit the answer. My part in the project was preventing the caching. you can go through the links :) I guess it might work out .

Comment: I have doubts whether it is about Storage. Cache of objects displayed in GridView seems to me more like a global variable than exact files or folders. I'll try with flags.

Comment: Ok, I solved my problem. Important is to have NavigationCacheMode enabled. In OnNavigatedTo method I just check whether list which to I saved data from database contains any elements. At first page opening it is empty so I load data from database to my list. Thus enabling NavigationCacheMode data in variables are stored in cache, and loaded while navigating to this page. Some flags may be required.

I'll post it as answer in 6 hours. Can't do it now because my reputation is too low.

Comment: Just wanted to know weather it worked or not. it's ok with the reputation issue :-)

Comment: ` NavigationCacheMode `  yes that is necessary to force save pages in cache :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved my problem. Important is to have NavigationCacheMode enabled. In OnNavigatedTo method I just check whether list which to I saved data from database contains any elements. At first page opening it is empty so I load data from database to my list. Thus enabling NavigationCacheMode, data in variables are stored in cache, and loaded while navigating to this page. Some flags may be required.