# Perfomance of topbar menu - mysql or json

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, performance

I have a php,jquery,foundation ecommerce website with a topbar menu that when document ready i do a ajax call to get the top images and description of each category in the menu.

the top images will not suffer daily changes so i could store the result in a json file and by that i wouldn't do a mysql conection on every page.

(but i have to do a page when the admin of ecommerce does an update that updates json file)

my question: is it worth it? is there other alternative like store the incoming ajax call on cache?

thanks

Comment: What exactly are you sending in the JSON response? image urls? image content in base64? something else? Please provide an example...

Comment: @ProGM its only the url. example: {
mulher/toucados: "SPOT_2013.jpg#Toucados#Toucado de sisal oval com aplicação de véu e laço. Pode ser fabricado por pedido em qualquer outra cor."
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a database table and save a cached version of the JSON response server side, updating it after each update (manually or with some versioning method)

Example:

php (pseudocode):

```
if (is_JSON_changed()) //some mechanism to check if the cache is not valid
{
    $query = Get infos from DB;
    $array = convert $query to array;
    $string = json_encode($array);
    file_put_contents("/tmp/cache.json", $string);
    echo $string;
} else {
    file_get_contents("/tmp/cache.json");
}
```

You can, in addition, use http cache headers:
[How to use HTTP cache headers with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971721/how-to-use-http-cache-headers-with-php)