# AngularJS ng-repeat image loading issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, image-loading

I've recently started to use AngularJS on my projects and I've come across a big problem using ngRepeat to load thumbnails from a dynamic array into a DIV.

Since I won't be explaining the entire application here, I'll reproduce an isolated situation where the problem occurs.

Let's suppose I have an image tag with ngRepeat directive like this:

```html
<img ng-repeat='n in [] | range: explorer.loadedLog.screenshotsNum' ng-src='getss.php?degenerated={{explorer.selectedLog}}&index={{n+1}}'>
```

Assuming that range is a custom filter that generates an array with explorer.loadedLog.screenshotsNum(variable modified by AJAX requests) elements and explorer.selectedLog is a string modified by AJAX requests. *I feel like these informations are almost irrelevant cause a tested it with common dynamic arrays and came across the same problem.*

The point is: when *explorer.loadedLog.screenshotsNum* and *explorer.selectedLog* are changed, all the new images have to be loaded.

I have a button for changing these values. When I first click it(at the first loading), it goes okay. If I wait for all the images to be loaded and change these values again, the new images are still loaded with no problems. But if I change it and change it again **BEFORE** all the images were loaded, it will load **ALL** the images that were left and then start loading the images that currently have to be loaded.

I mean, I don't know if I clearly explained this, but I thought if I modified these vars, the *"old"* images would just stop being loaded. But, somehow, they are still being loaded in background like the *DOM* from those were still somewhere in the document, and the **"new" images' loading gets delayed**. I actually wanted to stop the "old" images from being loaded and start loading the "new" images. I think it has to do with the way ngRepeat works, but I really wonder if there's no way to get through this without changing too much.

If I could solve this problem, the ngRepeat choice would be the best for me. But I still accept any other suggestion.

**EDIT:**

I've just noticed the obvious: when you set "src", **it will make the request to the server and it won't stop even if you remove/change img src**, so it has nothing to do with the way *ngRepeat* works but actually with the way `<img>` works. So, for my needs, *window.stop()* did the job(because my application doesn't have any restrictions to this), but I still wonder how I could make things work if I had any other images loading on the page simultaneously, since **I couldn't simply call window.stop()**. There is a way I can prevent an `<img>` from loading, so I could iterate over all the `<img>` elements inside a container and **prevent them from loading one-by-one?**

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to modify `getss.php` and add HTTP caching headers to the response? It won't change the browser trying to fetch the image when setting the `src` property, but it will fetch the image from the browser cache instead.

This should be helpful: [How to use HTTP cache headers with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971721/how-to-use-http-cache-headers-with-php)