# SESSION var not being cleared?

Tags: php, session, global-variables

page1.php

```
$for = $_GET['name'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['new'] = $for;
session_write_close();
header('Location: http://newwebsite.com);
```

page2.php

```
<?php
$new = '';
session_start();
$new = $_SESSION['new'];

?>

<script>  
    $(document).ready(function()
    {    
        <?php if($new != '') { ?>
        var banner = document.getElementById("A");
        var hiddenInput = document.getElementById("B");
        banner.innerHTML = <?php echo "'".$new."'" ?>;
        hiddenInput.value = <?php echo "'".$new."'" ?>;
        <?php }

        if(session_destroy())
        {
            unset($_SESSION['new']);
        }
        ?>
    });
</script>
```

I get my data from page1.php but when it never seems to get cleared.

If I do

```
print_r($_SESSION);
```

It results in empty output, but next time I come to the page with a different variable from page1.php it still shows me the older variable. What can I do?

Comment: The PHP code *does not* run *in* the JavaScript handler.. the formatting looks "suspicious" at best.

Comment: you need use more soap to wash then.

Comment: I don't know what you're saying @user2864740 - I changed some vars to post here. It works in my code.  I need to know what the issue is with the variable not being unset.. or appearing unset by the data not cleared?

Comment: Why bother with `session_destroy()`? Just `unset` the variable

Comment: @Machavity When I go to page1 and send- it goes to page 2 and displays as normal.  If I go back and go through the same process (with a different selection) it shows the the first result again.  With destroy or unset, or both.

Comment: Cache problem 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971721/how-to-use-http-cache-headers-with-php